Python recursion limits and functools.cache
sys.setrecursionlimit doesn't appear to affect functions declared using the @cache decorator:
from functools import cache
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

@cache
def f1(n):
    if n == 1: return 1
    return n * f1(n-1)

mycache = {}
def f2(n):
    if n in mycache:
        return mycache[n]
    if n == 1: val = 1
    else: val = n * f2(n-1)
    mycache[n] = val
    return val

f2(90000) # this works
f1(600) # this fails at a depth of 500 with the error:
# "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

The RecursionError thrown is also different than the usual "maximum recursion depth exceeded" when too many recursive calls are made.
I can't seem to replicate this without using @cache - custom decorators or callable class instances seem to respect the recursion limit.
What's going on here, and is there a way to change the recursion limit for functions declared using @class?

@moooeeeep While there are some similarities between the questions, I think they're ultimately unrelated - that post talks about the decorator multiplying the number of stack levels used, where my issue is that setting the recursion limit with sys.setrecursionlimit doesn't appear to affect the limit for the cached function at all.

I can't seem to reproduce the exact bug on my system (python 3.12.5). f1(600) works just fine, though f1(90000) still fails with the error you mention.

I think this is a bug in CPython: 3.12 setrecursionlimit is ignored in connection with @functools.cache

With Python 3.13 (3.13.0rc1), your code presented in this question runs without any errors.

As it is currently presented, the code seems to run without the error in a python:3.12.6 docker container. (Except for an unrelated ValueError: Exceeds the limit (4300 digits) for integer string conversion;)

@larsks I think they increased the limit at some point. Try f1(2000) or so. (I vaguely remember the limit also depending on configuration or machine type or so.)

Thanks for the help - looks like this was fixed in 3.12.6.

What makes you think so?

The fact that the linked github issue mentions backporting a fix from 3.13, and just now I installed 3.12.6 and was able to run the code without running into recursion issues.

Did you also try it with a larger number like the f1(2000) that I suggested? Or f1(20000)?

Ah, no - looks like it happens at 1000 instead of 500, but that's the only change.
